# Trigger python code on excel cell update using xlwings in macos

Tags: python, event-handling, delegates, xlwings

Working with free version of xlwings and excel running in mac os. Having searched and even after reading the xlwings documentation I've not been able to find a way to execute a python logic based on the cell update event.

The following code is a workaround I've done so far to poll the cell at a defined interval.

Is there a way to use delegate or events to trigger the execution?

```
import sys
import logging
import time

import xlwings as xw


app_logger = logging.getLogger('app_logger')

# Define the path to your Excel file
file_path = 'abc.xlsx'

# Define the cell to monitor for changes (e.g., 'Sheet1!A1')
cell_to_monitor = 'Sheet1!D2'

# Define a global variable to store the previous value of the cell
previous_value = None

if xw.apps.keys():
    app_logger.info('Using existing app')    
    app = xw.apps[xw.apps.keys()[0]]
else:
    app_logger.info('Launching new excel app')
    app = xw.App(visible=True)

app.activate(steal_focus=True)
wb = app.books.open(file_path) 
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

try:
    while True:
        # Get the current value of the cell
        current_value = sheet.range(cell_to_monitor).value

        # Check if the value has changed
        if current_value != previous_value:
            print(f'The value of {cell_to_monitor} has changed!')
            print(f'Old value: {previous_value}')
            print(f'New value: {current_value}')

            # Update the initial value to the current value
            previous_value = current_value

        # Wait for a second before checking again
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Close the Excel file when the program is terminated
    wb.close()
    app.quit()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mac os, but are you able to use a procedure in VBA for a change event like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change), and then add a `RunPython(...)` line to this procedure?